# Jquery Flot Xaxis to column formatting

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a bar chart with > 100 bars and currently the xaxis labels are like so:

```
___________________
100   101   102   103
```

What I would like them to become is:

```
___________________
1     1     1     1
0     0     0     0
0     1     2     3
```

So technically this isn't rotating the xaxis 90 degrees but splitting the label by each character and inserting a break between each character.

I presume this kind of thing would be possible using:

```
tickFormatter: function(value) {
```

However it is not quite clear how to proceed to achieve this - any advise would be gladly received! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
xaxis: {
    tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
       return (''+val).split('').join("<br/>");
    }
}
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/55v0nsSSiqeTSfeuuunj?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly!! I did try myself to use split in a similar way but it kept giving me errors saying it wasn't valid. I now see why it went wrong. Thanks!